# finite difference method to the delayed damped wave equation

Tags: numerical-methods, delay-differential-equations, finite-difference-methods

I want to do the numerical simulations in MATLAB for the following partial delay differential equations with Dirichlet boundary condition. I need to know the simplest method to do that.
\begin{equation}
\left\{ 
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial ^{2}z}{\partial t^{2}}\left( x,t\right) 
&=\frac{\partial ^{2}z}{\partial x^{2}}\left( x,t\right) 
+v\left( t\right) \frac{\partial z}{\partial t}\left( x,t-r\right) , & t&\geq 0,~~ x\in \Omega  
\\ 
z\left(x,\theta\right)&=\sin\left(x\theta\right) , &\theta&\in \left[ -r,0\right]  & 
\end{aligned}
\right. 
\end{equation}

Here r denoting the delay is a positive real number, and  $\Omega =\left( 0,1\right) $ .

N.B: Thank you for your help

Comment: You are missing some condition that excludes the trivial solution $z=0$. Is it to be assumed that $z(x,t)=0$ for all $t<0$? Did you solve similar problems before, esp. DE with delays, when yes, describe the methods used. What would be your first approach and how did it fail?

Comment: thank you Lutzl. I would like to inform you that I am a beginner on the use of numerical methods,

Comment: If you are just a beginner in numerical methods, then it is rather courageous to start with (second order) delay-differential equations. The easiest you can do is set $h=r/n$ and apply the Euler method to the first-order (in $t$) system $$∂_tz=w+vz(.,t-r),~~ ∂_tw=∂_x^2z$$ as in $$w_{k+1} = w_k+h∂_x^2z_k,~~ z_{k+1}=z_k+hw_k+v_kz_{k-n}.$$ In $x$ direction you apply some discretization or Fourier expansion and realize $∂_x^2$ according to the framework.